# Call method right after permission allowed

Tags: android

I have a code like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            String fileName = edtFileName.getText().toString() ;
            String content = edtContent.getText().toString();

            if (canReadAndWrite())
                createFile(fileName,content);
        }
```

When user clicked on a button the application asks him/her for permission but for first time the canReadAndWrite() method returns false . How can I solve this issue ? I can use onRequestPermissionsResult but it seems not reasonable because I don't know where the user clicked on the button (if we have many methods and buttons ) also the variables like fileName and content is local and I have to declare another variable as global 
.
this is my permission function code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <=23){
        return true;
    }else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this
            ,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1234);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1234:
           if(grantResults[0] == == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //Do what ever you want to do...
            }
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have three buttons and call canReadAndWrite() for three times . How I can find out which button clicked ? the method that you write is for when we have just one command no ?

Comment: you can use do it by using Request Code, after every call give a different Request code and based of that request code you can do what ever you want to do

Comment: in your case 1234 is your request code. change it for every button clicked.